# What is the best Lua wrapper for C++?

Tags: c++, lua

I am looking for a class to export my c++ functions and classes to lua and call C++ functions from lua.

I have found few but I am interested in user impressions over usability/ stability / community support.

So if you used such a wrapper please help.

- luabind

  - looks good
- tolua/tolua++

  - http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~celes/tolua/
  - http://www.codenix.com/~tolua/
  - latest update 2009
- luna

  - http://lua-users.org/wiki/LunaWrapper
  - small (53-line)
- luawrapper

  - https://code.google.com/p/luawrapper/
  - beta ? is stable   enough ?

Using boost is not a problem since si already used in my project.

Comment: There is no "best" of any technology. There is technology, that better fits your needs. Having said that, this question can not have one distinct correct answer and therefor should not be asked on stack overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Your list is missing SWIG (http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Lua.html)

Comment: Another option: https://code.google.com/p/lualite/

Comment: @scones: Pls read the question again. I don't want to compare scripting engines, but C++ wrappers over Lua (same technology [C++ and Lua], different implementation [the wrapper]). SWING is more than a wrapper.

Comment: @vlg789 I was not talking about SWING or SWIG, but the style of question. You may have mistaken me for user1654209 ? My point is, that the act of `comparing` itself should not be on Stackoverflow. Comparisons can contain subjective opinions and lack of information, both of which can lead to discussion, but not a single correct answer (every answer can be equally correct). There are sites for that. (ie http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ )

Comment: @scones: Note that comparison questions aren't really on-topic for Prog.SE either.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok, i have learned something then. The notes on meta and the faq were not quite clear on that. thanks

Comment: @vlg789 Are you mistaking SWIG for SWING :) SWIG generates wrappers that allows you to call C++ code from LUA (and many other target languages).I thought that was what you wanted.

Comment: closed as not constructive is a lame resolution for this topic. I understand that the meaning of `StackExachange` is to exchange experience. If I want this information: A comparison between some libraries/wrappers that are doing same (more or less) same job (in this case easing the work with Lua) what th is StackExachange forum that should be used ? PS: scones I didn't confused you with user1654209. Just responded to both question in the same post.

Comment: Sometimes phrasing the question as a problem to solve can help. E.g. "I want to expose some of my code to Lua where the calling code should be able to do X, Y and use feature Y. What wrapper can do that?".